# Stop log4net sending console output to log file?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4net

Is there a way to stop log4net from sending console output to the log file, or is this mandatory? I want only log4net specific logging to appear in the log file, not whatever has been piped from the console?

EDIT just to be clear, if I do:

```
System.Console.WriteLine("test")
```

it appears in the log file- which I do **not** want.

My config looks like:

```xml
<log4net debug="false">
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="C:\Log\Log.txt" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Size" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
        <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

Comment: That sounds very strange... Change debug="false" to true and check log4net's output.

Comment: Very strange. Don't see that behaviour (either 1.2.11 or 1.2.12). Are you sure there is something other than log4net capturing and redirecting Console output?

Comment: Something else is swallowing the output, nothing to do with log4net. put a write as first statement of program, and step through it.